# The difference between perfect Perfectly orderable graph and Perfect Elimination Ordering?

Tags: graph-theory

I am currently trying to learn in depth different concepts in graph theory. I can not quite understand what the difference is between **Perfectly orderable graph and Perfect Elimination Ordering?**

I would be happy to help with this.
Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chordal_graph

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectly_orderable_graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfectly orderable graph is a ***graph*** which has a perfect ordering.

A vertex order $<$ of $G$ is perfect if and only if $G$ contains no $P_4$ $abcd$ with $a < b$ and $d < c$.

A perfect elimination ordering in a graph is an ***ordering*** of the vertices of the graph such that, for each vertex $v,$ $v$ and the neighbors of $v$ that occur after $v$ in the order form a clique.
[Explained/simpler definition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739150/definition-of-perfect-elimination-ordering)